# Read from sessionStorage by ngStorage AngularJS that was saved by another library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, session-storage, ng-storage

In the browser session storage we have

```
`mykey` `myvalue`
```

where mykey is in the Key column of the Session Storage section
and
where myvalue is in the Value column of the Session Storage section
Everything's clear.

ngStorage (an AngularJS module) implemented in the project and works fine - writes and reads values that was written by ngStorage. However it stores value not as

```
mykey myvalue
```

but as

```
ngStorage-mykey "myvalue"
```

(two different things he does - adds prefix `ngStorage-` and wraps myvalue with "").

The question is: how to read session value by ngStorage that was saved by another (not an AngularJS module)?

As result, `$sessionStorage.mykey` won't get `myvalue` at all that was saved not by ngStorage.

It is possible without hacks to change the prefix ngStorage- with anything else, but another problem is "" wrappers.

So, any ideas how to read the values by ngStorage that were set NOT by ngStorage (that means without any prefixes prefix and not wrapped by "" )?

Again, by default, if you'd like to save `Hello World` text by $sessionStorage.message = "Hello World"; then ngStorage will add prefix by default (may be changed) and will add " " to the value like this:

`ngStorage-message`  `"Hello World"`

But I need to read 
`message`   `Hello World`

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the serializer / deSerializer used by ngStorage are angular.toJson / angular.fromJson. This is configurable through the provider.

angular.toJson would wrap a string with ".

You can do this in your module config after injecting $sessionStorageProvider,

```
$sessionStorageProvider.setKeyPrefix('');

$sessionStorageProvider.setSerializer(mySerializer);
$sessionStorageProvider.setDeserializer(myDeserializer);

function mySerializer(obj) {
    if(angular.isObject(obj)) {
        return angular.toJson(obj);
    }

    return obj;
}

function myDeserializer(str) {
    if(str && str.charAt(0) === '"') {
        return angular.fromJson(str);
    }

    return str;
}
```